# Verify EC signature

Tags: c#, digital-signature, azure-keyvault

I've created a new key in Azure Key Vault, where the key type is EC with curve P-256.

I was able to use the [sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/sign/sign?tabs=HTTP) operation using the EC key and I also can [verify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/verify/verify?tabs=HTTP) it using REST API.

My goal now is to extract the public key details as JWK, and share them with a 3rd party that will not be able to use the REST API. But before sharing them, I've tried to verify how this will work on my local machine, but I was not able to validate it.

Here is my code with what I have tried:

```
// x and y points from JWK
string x = "melmeVA/KKt+kTRGljKubiohqcwD9A65dyX3nxqxUg8=";
string y = "wSOw9N8jkoeMgdNMCeAAKop4kR9f8jrvDOZnpkc9Fw0=";

ECDsa key = ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
{
    Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
    Q = new ECPoint
    {
        X = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(x),
        Y = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(y)
    }
});

var header = "{\"alg\":\"ES256\"}";
var body = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
var toBeSigned = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(header) + "." + Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(body);

var hash = SHA256.Create();
var digest = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toBeSigned));
Console.WriteLine(Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(digest));

// Sign API response (using the digest from above)
var signature = "ZBPn3jJpccDPasbasOfocjSkHpRA0bmn2963IMzraa50H5v5ovtavtilwpu7zf_8McwfR9qCrkXMiXBOf4W8BQ";

var publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(key.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo());
Console.WriteLine(publicKey);

var result = key.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toBeSigned), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I always get a false result.

Comment: The signature must be Base64url decoded (and not Utf8 encoded) on verification.

Comment: @Topaco: Thank you! It worked. Now the result is true.

Comment: I've changed only this line `var result = key.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toBeSigned), Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(signature), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working snippet based on @Topaco's comment:

```
// x and y coordinates from the JWK
string x = "change_this_with_xCoordinates";
string y = "change_this_with_xCoordinates";

ECDsa key = ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
{
    Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
    Q = new ECPoint
    {
        X = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(x),
        Y = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(y)
    }
});

var header = "{\"alg\":\"ES256\"}"; // the content of the header must be exactly the same as the one used at signing
var body = "{\"key\":\"value\"}"; // the content of the body must be exactly the same as the one used at signing
var toBeSigned = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(header) + "." + Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(body);

// Digest is needed to be passed in the body of the sign operation.
var hash = SHA256.Create();
var digest = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toBeSigned));
Console.WriteLine(Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(digest));

// API response (using the digest from above)
var signature = "change_this_with_signature_response";

var result = key.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toBeSigned), Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(signature), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This snippet can validate the signature and will return a true result.